# How to write a bunch of numbers in a column in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

When I use this code in Linux (echo {1..100} 1.txt), it writes numbers of 1 to 100 in rows like 1, 2, 3, ... 100. Something I need is a code to write these numbers vertically like below.

```
1
2
3
4
.
.
100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `tr` to convert spaces to linebreaks:

```sh
echo {1..100} | tr ' ' '\n'
```